# Entity splitting across three tables with two different keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following database schema which I can't change:

[image: database schema]

The relationship between the `TM_USER` and `TM_USER_DETAIL` tables uses the `USR_ID` and `UDT_USR_ID` columns.  The data type of `USR_ID` is `int`.

The relationship between the `TM_USER` and `TM_MEMBERSHIP_USERS` tables uses the `USR_USER_KEY` and `USR_ID` columns.  The data type of `USR_USER_KEY` is a `guid` represented as a `string`.

My question is how to map this using Entity Framework?

Here is my entity:

```
public class User
{
    // from table TM_USER
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    // from table TM_USER_DETAIL
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    // from table TM_MEMBERSHIP_USERS
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

And my entity configuration:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new { p.Key, p.Id, p.Username });

            map.ToTable("TM_USER");

            map.Property(p => p.Key).HasColumnName("USR_USER_KEY");
            map.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("USR_ID");
            map.Property(p => p.Username).HasColumnName("USR_USER_NAME");
        });

        Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new { p.Forename, p.Surname });

            map.ToTable("TM_USER_DETAIL");

            map.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UDT_USR_ID");
            map.Property(p => p.Forename).HasColumnName("UDT_FORENAME");
            map.Property(p => p.Surname).HasColumnName("UDT_SURNAME");
        });

        Map(map =>
        {
            map.Properties(p => new { p.IsApproved });

            map.ToTable("TM_MEMBERSHIP_USERS");

            map.Property(p => p.Key).HasColumnName("USR_ID");
            map.Property(p => p.IsApproved).HasColumnName("USR_ISAPPROVED");
        });

        HasKey(user => user.Id);
    }
}
```

When I try to query the `Users`, I get the following error:

> Properties for type 'User' can only be mapped once. The non-key
>   property 'Id' is mapped more than once. Ensure the Properties method
>   specifies each non-key property only once.

Is it possible to configure EF to map a single entity to three tables in this way using different keys for each relationship?

I have posted a sample solution here:
https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/entity-splitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You should split your model into different models. Furthermore, the relationship does not make sense for me. In your schema, `TM_USER` has many `TM_USER_DETAIL`, that relationship allows an User to have several forenames and surnames. I think that was not your intention. In a common scenario, the `TM_USER` has only one `TM_USER_DETAIL`. So, your model should be something like this:

```
TM_USER
-------------
UserId - PK
Username 
Key 
Deleted

TM_USER_DETAIL
---------------
UserId - PK - FK TM_USER
Forename 
Surname
```

To make the model even simpler, we can merge `TM_USER_DETAIL` with `TM_USER`. Like this:

```
TM_USER
-------------
UserId - PK
Username 
Key 
Forename 
Surname 
Deleted
```

The same thing values to the relationship between `TM_User` and `TM_MEMBERSHIP_USERS`. So, we can merge them. Like this:

```
TM_USER
-------------
UserId - PK
Username 
Key 
Forename 
Surname
IsApproved  
Deleted
```

Now, we have to create the `User` class in order to use it in the Entity Framework.

```
public class User
{
    // from table TM_USER 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }


    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("TM_USER");

        Property(p => p.Key).HasColumnName("USR_USER_KEY");
        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("USR_ID");
        Property(p => p.Username).HasColumnName("USR_USER_NAME");
        Property(p => p.Forename).HasColumnName("UDT_FORENAME");
        Property(p => p.Surname).HasColumnName("UDT_SURNAME");
        Property(p => p.IsApproved).HasColumnName("USR_ISAPPROVED");

        HasKey(user => user.Id);
    }
}
```

If you still want to use 3 different tables, you have to create 3 different classes, with their respective properties, mapping them to their respective tables.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately I can't change the schema as it's from a 3rd party app.  I also agree that the relationships could be improved, but that's what I have to work with in this case.

Comment: in that case, you have to create a separated model for each table

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to, but we're going to have to make the EF model reflect the database.